LZMW compression algorithm always inflates data
I've tried to implement LZMW compression algorithm by modifying an implementation of LZW:
main.cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

uint32_t write_pointer = 0;
uint32_t read_pointer = 0;
uint32_t dictionary_index;

const uint32_t BUFFER_SIZE = 65536;
char* buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];

int32_t read_input_file(std::ifstream& fs_in, uint32_t length)
{
    //Case: reading to the middle of the buffer
    if (write_pointer + length < BUFFER_SIZE)
    {
        fs_in.read(buffer + write_pointer, length);

        int32_t bytes_read = fs_in.gcount();
        write_pointer += bytes_read;

        return length - bytes_read;
    }

    //Case: reading to the end of the buffer
    if (write_pointer + length == BUFFER_SIZE)
    {
        fs_in.read(buffer + write_pointer, length);

        int32_t bytes_read = fs_in.gcount();
        write_pointer += bytes_read;
        write_pointer -= (write_pointer >= BUFFER_SIZE) * BUFFER_SIZE;

        return length - bytes_read;
    }

    //Case: reading with crossing the end of the buffer
    {
        fs_in.read(buffer + write_pointer, BUFFER_SIZE - write_pointer);

        int32_t bytes_read = fs_in.gcount();
        write_pointer += bytes_read;
        write_pointer -= (write_pointer >= BUFFER_SIZE) * BUFFER_SIZE;

        if (write_pointer != 0)
            return bytes_read;

        fs_in.read(buffer, length - bytes_read);

        int32_t bytes_read_2 = fs_in.gcount();
        write_pointer += bytes_read_2;
        write_pointer -= (write_pointer >= BUFFER_SIZE) * BUFFER_SIZE;

        return length - (bytes_read + bytes_read_2);
    }
}

char read_buffer()
{
    char buf = buffer[read_pointer++];
    read_pointer %= BUFFER_SIZE;
    return buf;
}

void unread_buffer()
{
    read_pointer += BUFFER_SIZE - 1;
    read_pointer %= BUFFER_SIZE;
}

uint32_t buffer_bytes_available()
{
    //Safe if (BUFFER_SIZE + write_pointer - read_pointer) < 2 * BUFFER_SIZE
    return (BUFFER_SIZE + write_pointer - read_pointer) -
        ((BUFFER_SIZE + write_pointer - read_pointer) >= BUFFER_SIZE) * BUFFER_SIZE;
}

uint8_t bits_per_dictionary_id()
{
    uint32_t index = dictionary_index;
    uint32_t result = 1;

    while (index >>= 1)
        result++;

    return result;
}

class Node
{
public:
    uint32_t id;
    std::string token;

    Node(uint32_t id);
    ~Node();
};

Node::Node(uint32_t id)
{
    this->id = id;
}

Node::~Node()
{
    std::string().swap(token);
}

void compress_file(std::string file_in, std::string file_out)
{
    std::ifstream fs_in(file_in, std::ifstream::binary);
    std::ofstream fs_out(file_out, std::ofstream::binary);

    bool input_file_end_reached = false;
    bool last_index_to_write = false;

    std::unordered_map<std::string, uint32_t> dictionary;

    //Initialize dictionary
    for (dictionary_index = 0; dictionary_index < 256; dictionary_index++)
        dictionary.insert(std::pair<std::string, uint32_t>(string(1, static_cast<char>(dictionary_index)),
            dictionary_index));

    uint8_t data_out = 0;
    int8_t data_out_position = 7;

    //Read the first chunk of file
    if (read_input_file(fs_in, BUFFER_SIZE - 1))
        input_file_end_reached = true;

    std::string previous_match = "";

    while (buffer_bytes_available() > 0)
    {
        //Find the entry that is not yet present in dictionary
        std::string current_data;
        int32_t index;
        int32_t last_found_index = -1;

        do
        {
            index = -1;

            if (buffer_bytes_available() == 0)
            {
                last_index_to_write = true;
                break;
            }

            current_data.push_back(read_buffer());

            std::unordered_map<std::string, uint32_t>::iterator it = dictionary.find(current_data);
            if (it != dictionary.end())
                index = last_found_index = it->second;
        } while (index != -1);

        //Last byte of new entry is not encoded by last_found_index
        if (buffer_bytes_available() > 0 && !last_index_to_write)
            unread_buffer();
        else
        {
            if (!last_index_to_write)
                unread_buffer();
            last_index_to_write = true;
        }

        //Write output
        for (int8_t i = bits_per_dictionary_id() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            data_out |= (((last_found_index >> i) & 0x01) << (data_out_position--));

            if (data_out_position < 0)
            {
                fs_out << data_out;
                data_out = 0;
                data_out_position = 7;
            }
        }

        //This code is one I added
        //Add new entry to dictionary
        dictionary.insert(
            std::pair<std::string, uint32_t>(previous_match + current_data, dictionary_index++));
        previous_match = current_data;

        //The code below is the original one
        //Add new entry to dictionary
        /*dictionary.insert(
            std::pair<std::string, uint32_t>(current_data, dictionary_index++));*/

            //Read next data chunk
        if (!input_file_end_reached)
            if (read_input_file(fs_in, BUFFER_SIZE - buffer_bytes_available() - 1))
                input_file_end_reached = true;
    }

    //If there is any leftover data, write it to the output file
    if (data_out_position != 7)
        fs_out << data_out;
}

void decompress_file(std::string file_in, std::string file_out)
{
    std::ifstream fs_in(file_in, std::ifstream::binary);
    std::ofstream fs_out(file_out, std::ofstream::binary);

    std::vector<Node*> dictionary;

    //Initialize dictionary
    for (dictionary_index = 0; dictionary_index < 256; dictionary_index++)
    {
        Node* node = new Node(dictionary_index);
        node->token.push_back(dictionary_index);
        dictionary.push_back(node);
    }

    bool input_file_end_reached = false;
    bool is_data_valid = true;

    //Read the first chunk of file
    if (read_input_file(fs_in, BUFFER_SIZE - 1))
        input_file_end_reached = true;

    uint8_t buf = read_buffer();
    uint8_t bits_read = 0;
    uint32_t data_read;

    while (buffer_bytes_available() > 0 || bits_read < 8)
    {
        data_read = 0;

        for (int8_t i = bits_per_dictionary_id() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            data_read <<= 1;
            data_read |= ((buf >> (7 - bits_read)) & 0x01);
            bits_read++;

            if (bits_read == 8)
            {
                if (buffer_bytes_available() == 0)
                {
                    if (i > 0)
                        is_data_valid = false;
                    break;
                }
                buf = read_buffer();
                bits_read = 0;
            }
        }

        if (!is_data_valid)
            break;

        //Skip on first pass of the loop
        if (dictionary_index > 256)
            //Complete previous dictionary entry
            dictionary[dictionary_index - 1]->token.push_back(dictionary[data_read]->token[0]);

        //Create new incomplete dictionary entry
        Node* entry = new Node(dictionary_index++);
        entry->token = dictionary[data_read]->token;
        dictionary.push_back(entry);

        //Write data encoded by index
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < dictionary[data_read]->token.size(); i++)
            fs_out << dictionary[data_read]->token[i];

        //Read next data chunk
        if (!input_file_end_reached)
            if (read_input_file(fs_in, BUFFER_SIZE - buffer_bytes_available() - 1))
                input_file_end_reached = true;
    }

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < dictionary.size(); i++)
        delete dictionary[i];
}

int main() {

    compress_file("archive", "output");

    decompress_file("output", "decompress");

    return 0;
}

The only big change compared to original LZW code were made to compress_file function: instead of just adding current_data to dictionary, a concatenation of previous_match and current_data is added, after which current_data is assigned as previous_match. I also changed input data type from vector<uint8_t> to string.
The problem with my implementation - the data is inflated rather than compressed, although original data is restored without any loss. I've tested it with several file collections, and compression inflates them around 2.5x-3x compared to original data:
canterbury:  2,810,994 bytes   ->  7,205,628 bytes
large:       11,159,552 bytes  ->  31,369,226 bytes
calgary:     3,251,759 bytes   ->  8,415,799 bytes

Original LZW implementation actually compresses data:
canterbury:  2,810,994 bytes   ->  977,326 bytes
large:       11,159,552 bytes  ->  3,507,560 bytes
calgary:     3,251,759 bytes   ->  1,353,242 bytes

Any ideas what exactly goes wrong in code I edited?

Ok, so there's a bug. You're expecting us to debug your code for you?

@MarkAdler I've tried to find the source of the problem, haven't found it and decided to ask on StackOverflow, expecting help from people smarter than me. I don't know who are "us" you mentioned, but I'm not forcing you or anyone else to do anything (although it seems you're the only one answering compression-related questions, so my chances of getting answer from anyone else are close to zero).

To expect a response here from "us" (those that might put some effort into your question), you would need to do enough debugging on your own to be able to point so something much more specific than "my code doesn't do what I expect", and providing a wall of code to wade through. Just trying to help you with writing a viable question.
